Loop over years in SPSS Syntax
I have this code.
Select if (syear=1995 and Niedriglohn=1).
Frequencies NiedriglohnDauer.

I want to have the Frequencies of Niedriglohndauer for the year 1995 to 2020 each if Niedriglohn=1.

This will do it:
Select if Niedriglohn=1.
sort cases by syear.
split file by syear.
Frequencies NiedriglohnDauer.
split file off.

